# Entering Route53 Nameservers gives me errors on Godaddy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nameservers

I have set up an elastic IP for my `EC2` instance on `Amazon Web Services`.
I have also set up the correct `Record Sets` in `Route53`.

However, when I try to add the name servers that are given to me into GoDaddy to point to my domain, I am getting an error:

> You entered invalid characters. Valid characters include letters, numbers, and periods.

There are four name servers and they look something like this:

```
ns-***.awsdns-**.com. 
ns-****.awsdns-**.co.uk.
ns-***.awsdns-**.net.
ns-****.awsdns-**.org.
```

Where the `*`'s are numbers.  It also won't let me add more than 2 name servers as it is.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In the GoDaddy Domain Control Panel, don't launch the DNS manager...  Instead, click on the "Set Nameservers" link, just to the left of that.

Select the radio button next to "I have specific nameservers for my domains" and then populate the 4 nameserver hostnames provided by Route 53, into those 4 boxes.

Don't enter the dot at the end of each nameserver name into the boxes.

Comment: The dot at the end appeared to be the issue.  My mistake.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yep. It's the trailing dots that kill it. Leave them off and you'll be good to go. Neither the Level 1 or Level 2 engineers in Godaddy's (usually very good) support team knew about this issue/solution. Have asked them to add it to their knowledge base

Answer (score 13):

You have to copy the aws nameservers without '.' at the end and add to the following name server field.

aws nameservers:

-ns-***.awsdns-**.com

-ns-****.awsdns-**.co.uk

-ns-***.awsdns-**.net

-ns-****.awsdns-**.org

In the Godaddy setting:

Domains ->set nameserver->custom->ns-***.awsdns-**.com

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of nameservers, with one you can define nameservers that share your domain, like ns1.domain.com and the other where you can specify 1 or more name servers to resolve queries for your domain.

I believe you are trying to update the first one, when you should update the second one.

Comment: In route53, it has my url under name (someurl.com), then type is "NS", and then under value it has those 4 values I have in my question above.  Trying just ns1.amazon.com instead of the customized one, gives me the error "You must enter a registered name server."  This is beyond frustrating at this point.  What does GoDaddy want me to enter as the name servers from Route53.

Comment: You don't define your own DNS servers. You set name servers for your domain. The tool your attempting to use is the incorrect one. Godaddy should have help documents pointing you to the correct page.

Comment: When adding NS records to Godaddy from AWS PLS  remove the dot from the end.