# Django nginx Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: django, nginx, x-frame-options

I have deployed a django web application on a server with nginx and uwsgi. I can access the site perfectly using the ip address.

I purchased a domain name say abc.example.com and pointed it to my ip address. Now when i go the domain name it loads a blank page and throws an error in browser console:

In Chrome:

```
Refused to display 'ip address' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

In Mozilla:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: 'ip address' does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

**The point is I dont have any iframe in my whole Application.**

What is this error and how can i solve it?

When i go to application using ip address it works perfectly as it is supposed to be. Then what is the problem with domain? I double checked the settings in dns zone on godaddy but couldn't figure out anything.

Comment: Django `settings.py` has `X_FRAME_OPTIONS` parameter. Try changing it's value to `DENY`, according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/clickjacking/#setting-x-frame-options-for-all-responses . If this will not help, try to disable middleware to see what happens.

Comment: The error indicates that there is an iframe there. What is the result when you select "show source" in the web browser?

Comment: @KidBinary disabling the middleware worked.

Comment: @ManishGupta: I see... This middleware for some reason thinks that you trying to load your website from a different origin. That clearly points that problem is with GoDaddy configuration. Maybe it's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515498/entering-route53-nameservers-gives-me-errors-on-godaddy#comment34263478_22517935 ?

Answer (score 53):

In 'settings.py' file, add these two lines. It may help you.

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'

XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS = ['POST','GET','OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'DELETE']
```

Comment: its secure allowall? Can I allow just a specific domain? thanks

Comment: Perfect answer. I was looking out for a perfect solution for this error, and you had given the exact answer which I was actually expected. Thank you.

Comment: this exactly what i was looking for.. thanks <3

Comment: X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN' works and is safer.

Comment: This work for me. thank you