# Django CMS - cookie cutter : The form could not be loaded. Please check that the server is running correctly

Tags: django, content-management-system, django-cms, cookiecutter

I started learning web development at a company, and was tasked with making a simple app in cookiecutter django, and then integrating django-cms into it.

I used django cookie-cutter to start a project, and then integrated django-cms into the project following this guide :

https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/install.html

After some initial trouble, I managed to get it going.
After that, the next step was to add my "polls" app to the project and integrate Django CMS in it aswell.

For that I followed this tutorial :

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/03-integrating_applications.html#incorporate-the-polls-application

I managed to get all the way to the end of the last link, and then on step 6, this happens.

Every time I try to delete a plugin from my site, or when I click create on the CMS toolbar i get this error (note: if I log in to /admin, I can create the page, but not via the cms menu bar on the actual website) :

```
The form could not be loaded. Please check that the server is running correctly.
```

The server is all good. No errors there.

And in the console :

```
Refused to display 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/cms_wizard/create/?page=5&language=en&edit&cms_path=/home/?edit&language=en&structure' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

bundle.toolbar.min.js:1 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

I have been googling for the past two days, and I just cannot figure it out.
Any help would be greatly appreciated !

I have pushed the files I changed on my github, if you need any other info please let me know, I will include it right away.

```
https://github.com/sandilukez/cms-django-cookie
```

I tried everything I could find online, with no luck !

Comment: What version of django and django-cms are you using? Cookie cutter talks about using django 2.2 but CMS doesn't support 2.2 at the moment. That support comes in the next release, 3.7.

Comment: Im actually using 2.2, had no idea !

Answer (score 3):

The answer above is a close one, at least point where the problem is, but the answer, `X_FRAME_OPTIONS = "ALLOWALL"` might cause security problems.
as it is mentioned in the django documentation

> Modern browsers honor the X-Frame-Options HTTP header that indicates whether or not a resource is allowed to load within a frame or iframe. If the response contains the header with a value of SAMEORIGIN then the browser will only load the resource in a frame if the request originated from the same site.

For django cms to be able to open iframes inside the website we should put `X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'` in our settings. So that we don't allow other website to include our website as iframe but let django cms work properly.
For more information, here is the related documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/clickjacking/

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing this is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694881/django-nginx-refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to). You probably have the same error in the console right?

You should therefore add the following in your `settings/local.py`:

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = "ALLOWALL"
XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS = ["POST", "GET", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "DELETE"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Anser update 11 july 2021

i success fixed the issue thanks lot @user2135738

version :
[image]

settings.py  file inside the your django project

```
#django cms allow all
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = "ALLOWALL"
XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_METHODS = ["POST", "GET", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "DELETE"]
```

[image]